# How to create custom progressDialog

Tags: java, android, android-dialogfragment

At any devices we have different position of progressBar inside of the progressDialog. So I need to customize it.

When I try like this:

```
public class CustomProgressDialog extends ProgressDialog {

    public CustomProgressDialog(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.progress_fragment_dialog);
    }
    }


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This progress dialog shows only progressBar without dialog. But I need dialog too.

Comment: http://islandofatlas.net/2014/03/29/android-custom-progress-dialog.html try this link

Answer (score 3):

Create custom dialog with progress bar in it for making it consistent for different devices.

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom);
dialog.setTitle("Title...");

// set the custom dialog components - title, ProgressBar and button
TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text);
text.setText("COUSTOM PROGRESS TITLE");
ProgressBar prog = (ProgressBar) dialog.findViewById(R.id.myprogress);
prog.setVisibilty(VISIBLE);

Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonOK);
   // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
   dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
        dialog.dismiss();
     }
});

dialog.show();
```

**layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/myprogress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"/>/>

     <Button
        android:id="@+id/dialogButtonOK"
        android:layout_width="100px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=" Ok "
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/myprogress"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Do you mean, that I don't need to create class that extends Dialog at all? But it's such many code every time when I want to use Progress Dialog!

Comment: you can also do that if you know how tackle with it otherwise you can so the same thing with this.