# How to set the size of ProgressDialog to wrap around progress circle

Tags: android, progressdialog

I'm using the following code to show a spinning circle while I'm loading data, but when I removed the dialog message, the dialog still takes the same width (when it was with a message), and the spinning circle are aligned to the left, but I want it to be centered and the dialog to be wrapped around it (to have the size of the spinning circle).

```
ProgressDialog mProgress;
mProgress = new ProgressDialog(this);
//mProgress.setMessage("loading...");
mProgress.setCancelable(false);
mProgress.show();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is default dialog of android, you can not change progress circle position but you can create your custom progress dialog. where you can set progress circle at any position. Here is the link and example that will help you to create your own custom progress dialog. [How to create custom progressDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42673330/how-to-create-custom-progressdialog)

http://islandofatlas.net/2014/03/29/android-custom-progress-dialog.html

Comment: Thank you Vatsal :)